# Exporting .csv file with error code inside saying "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, html, laravel

I used this code to export the report into excel (.csv)
But in the exported file right bellow the datas it shows some error saying error line 1026.
This is line 1026

```
$event_group_members = \App\EventGroupMembers::where('eg_id', '=',$event_group->eg_id)->get();
if ($event_group_members->count() > 0) {
    foreach ($event_group_members as $event_group_member) {
        $member = \App\User::find($event_group_member->user_id);
        if ($member) {
            $booking_status = \EUser::getEUserBookingStatusPayment($event_group_member->user_id, $booking_data->booking_id);
            $ar_data = array($chalet_name, $chalet_unit, $event_group->name, $booking_status, $member->first_name .' '. $member->last_name, $member->email, $member->phone);
            if ($addons->count() > 0){
                $addons_booked = \App\EventBookingCharges::where('charge_key', '=', 'add-ons')->where('user_id', '=', $event_group_member->user_id)->where('booking_id', '=', $booking_data->booking_id)->get();
                foreach ($addons as $addon){
                    if ($addons_booked->count() > 0) {
                        foreach ($addons_booked as $addon_booked){
                            $decoded = json_decode($addon_booked->json);
                            if ($decoded->addon_id == $addon->addon_id) {
                                array_push($ar_data, "yes");
                            } else {
                                array_push($ar_data, "no");
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        array_push($ar_data, "no");
                    }
                }
            }
            fputcsv($file, $ar_data);
        }
    }
}
```

I cant find whats wrong
I really hope you guys can help me with this

Comment: Which is `1026`? that's more than 1 line of code.

Comment: Just to show other line :D

Comment: Refractor to methods for what happens within the loops, that will improve readability. And will probably show errors better.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "Trying to get property of none object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the `$event_group` to locate your `eg_id`.

Comment: Yes I ended up removing the event_group and make it $eg_id instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is error you will get generally if you are accessing a relation model column where the related records doesn't exists. Its better to check relation available and proceed.

Comment: This only occur on one account. The other account exports just fine